# How to prevent 'UIColor' has no member 'systemBackground' ` and 'UIStatusBarStyle' has no member 'darkContent' in ionic/react v5 for ios?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-react

Writing a simple app, no plugins (yet) with Ionic react v 5.3.0

After ionic build, Xcode reports swift build error:
`Type 'UIStatusBarStyle' has no member 'darkContent' ios`
This happens with swift v 4.2 and swift v 5, ios deployment target 8, 9, 10, and 11

I attempt to solve by deleting and regenerating `node_modules` and `ios` directories per the instructions here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/native

Still seeing the issues in xcode with buildtime warnings and 4 Swift complie errors.
Two of those errors are `Type 'UIColor' has no member 'systemBackground'`  found in CapBridgeViewcontroller.swift from `Pods>Development Pods> Capacitor > Plugins`

```
    if let backgroundColor = (bridge!.config.getValue("ios.backgroundColor") as? String) ?? (bridge!.config.getValue("backgroundColor") as? String) {
      webView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(fromHex: backgroundColor)
      webView?.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(fromHex: backgroundColor)
    } else if #available(iOS 13, *) {
      // Use the system background colors if background is not set by user
      webView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
      webView?.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
    }
```

And the other two errors are:
`Type 'UIStatusBarStyle' has no member 'darkContent'` found in statusBar.swift

```
 public func setStatusBarDefaults() {
    if let plist = Bundle.main.infoDictionary {
      if let statusBarHidden = plist["UIStatusBarHidden"] as? Bool {
        if (statusBarHidden) {
          self.isStatusBarVisible = false
        }
      }
      if let statusBarStyle = plist["UIStatusBarStyle"] as? String {
        if (statusBarStyle == "UIStatusBarStyleDarkContent") {
          if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            self.statusBarStyle = .darkContent
          } else {
            self.statusBarStyle = .default
          }
        } else if (statusBarStyle != "UIStatusBarStyleDefault") {
          self.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and

```
  @objc func setStyle(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
    let options = call.options!

    if let style = options["style"] as? String {
      if style == "DARK" {
        bridge.setStatusBarStyle(.lightContent)
      } else if style == "LIGHT" {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
          bridge.setStatusBarStyle(.darkContent)
        } else {
          bridge.setStatusBarStyle(.default)
        }
      }
    }
    
    call.success([:])
  }
```

What I expect is that I can build my app from ionic cli and not have to modify swift code every time I build.  Is there a setting I could add in my ionic project that would prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capacitor requires Xcode 11 to build

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started/dependencies#ios-development

Answer above was found a: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/3338